# PHP data saving to database

Tags: php, database, save

==> index.php:

```
<form action="anotherpage.php" method="POST"/>
<br>Username: <input type="text" name="user_name"><br><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br><br>
Repeat:   <input type="password" name="pwd2"><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my index.php and I created an "anotherpage.php".

==> anotherpage.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use '.DB_NAME.': '.mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully!<br>';

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);
$sexuality = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sex']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, sexuality) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$sexuality."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: '. mysqli_error($con));
}

if(isset($_POST['user_name']) &&! empty($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['pwd2']) &&! empty($_POST['pwd2']) && isset($_POST['pwd']) &&! empty($_POST['pwd']) && isset($_POST['sex']) &&! empty($_POST['sex']) or die('PART\'S ARE NOT FILLED!')) 
{
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_name_up = strtoupper($user_name);
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwd2 = $_POST['pwd2'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];

    $fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "a");
    $savestring = $user_name . "," . $pwd.",".$pwd2.",".$sex." - ";
    fwrite($fp, $savestring);
    fclose($fp);
}
if($pwd == $pwd2 or die('DIFFERENT PASSWORDS!'))
{
    echo $user_name_up.' ALL TAKEN!<BR>THANK YOU!!!<br><h1>You data has been saved!</h1>';
}


?>
```

I can save the input to database now. But the think is i want to do this think if my if statement comes true. Otherwise even if the passwords dont match i save the input to database. How can i do that?

If i change the place of my code i get an error.

MANY THANKS FROM NOW! :)

Comment: Well, you open a text file, write the data to the file and close it once you're sure everything is OK.  php has [file functions](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php) so I really can't understand where your problem is?

Comment: You might want to look into using a database such as [MySQL](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql).

Comment: Well, there's `fwrite()` and `file_put_contents()` that you could Google for. You're sure to find OODLES on Google ;-)

Comment: And while you're at it, check the `flock` function

Comment: WELL GUYS THANK YOU! I FOUND OUT HOW TO SAVE THEM TO A FILE, NOW THE PROBLEM IS THAT I CANT SAVE TO DATABASE... :D EDITED POST! WAITING FOR COMMENTS...

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware of sql injections, please read the treat [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

The sql is misplaced, the part below must put into the same if statement as where you save the file.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (username, password, sexuality) VALUES ("$_POST[user_name]","$pwd","$sex")';

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
      die('Error: '. mysqli_error($con));
}
```

You have also change the quotes and add string concats to get it worked correctly

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, sexuality) VALUES ('".$_POST['user_name']."','".$pwd."','".$sex."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
      die('Error: '. mysqli_error($con));
}
```

But be aware the code above is still unsafe, the code below is a little more safe

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($pwd);
$sexuality = mysql_real_escape_string($sex);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, sexuality) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$sexuality."')";
```

Its not wise to save passwords directly into the database, please read the follow [How to change a SALT password in a database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056866/how-to-change-a-salt-password-in-a-database-using-php)